# Imported DE is not added onto All Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber-key

I have managed to import successfully the 2 records into DE (email, first name and last name). Then, I sent an email with this DE, the message indicates it successfully sent. However, the tracking showed 0 count sent and the 2 valid email addresses couldn't find in All subscriber list. Please help.

[image: DE]
[image: DE Records Page]
[image: Tracking showed 0 count sent]
[image: Couldn't find in All Subscriber]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to send an email, you need to have correctly configured Data Extension with [`Email Address` data type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5) field and of course, be [sendable with relationship](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_send_to_de_enhanced.htm&type=5) to the SubsriberKey.

You do have sendable DE and the relationship as well but your related field called `email` is `Text` data type.

What you need to do:

1. Change the `email` field’s data type to `Email Address` by deleting and adding back the field with the correct data type.
2. Once you will send an email, you will be able to find the subscriber in the All Subscribers list by searching by either Email Address or SubscriberKey (both attributes would have the same values in your case)

In your case, you could not find your subscriber because the `email` field is SubsriberKey but not an Email Address